# Make TableView Scroll Seamlessly with additional PanGesture to First FullScreen and Then the Content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

Hello, So I have implemented this behavior where UITableView PanGesture get dragged to fullscreen being in front of view behind (Pink View) by adding a PanGesture to UITableView gestures and I remove this gesture when the UITableView becomes fullscreen. After FullScreen TableView content can be scrolled.

What I want is the smooth transition when TableView gets dragged to FullScreen with the same drag movement that drag should automatically scroll the TableView content. Similarly when scroll downward if the tableview is showing the top row it should start scrolling down with the same gesture.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomView: UIView!
    let height = (UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.6) * -1;
    var panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.draggedView(_:)))
        bottomView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        tableView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
            bottomView.clipsToBounds = true
            bottomView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
            bottomView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]

    }

    @objc func draggedView(_ sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(bottomView)
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
        bottomViewTopConstraint.constant += translation.y
        if bottomViewTopConstraint.constant <= height {
            print("getting here \(height)")
            bottomViewTopConstraint.constant = height
            tableView.removeGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        }
        else if bottomViewTopConstraint.constant >= -24{
            bottomViewTopConstraint.constant = -24
        }
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        print(bottomViewTopConstraint.constant)
    }
    


}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }
    
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y == -50 {
            tableView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell : UITableViewCell!
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Row \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print ("Cell selected \(indexPath.row)")
    }
}
```

In **draggedView** I am removing PanGesture so table could scroll its content but for this to work user has to let go off his current gesture and do drag gesture again and same is the case with **scrollViewWillBeginDragging** where I re-add the pan gesture. I want the scroll behavior to switch seamlessly like its one scroll.

I want to implement the behavior like this dribble animation https://dribbble.com/shots/6571883-Food-Delivery-App

Answer (score 0):

What you need in this case is a nested scroll views structure. You should have total 3 scroll views.
Here is a link to such project that does the same thing as yours
[Twitter Profile](https://github.com/OfTheWolf/TwitterProfile).

I will try to explain in a nutshell what you have to do here.
Scroll view 1 should be on first half of screen, 2nd scroll view (in your case, a table view) on second half of screen. 3rd scroll view is behind these two scroll views & will cover whole screen.
Scrolling on 1st & 2nd scroll views should be disabled, all scroll events are to be handled with 3rd scroll view.

3rd scroll view content size should be equal to sum of 1st & 2nd scroll views. Upon scrollViewDidScroll event, 3rd scroll view will update content offset of 1st or 2nd scroll view depending upon the position of content offset.

I had a similar thing to implement in the past. My advice is to first try to understand this nested scroll view structure. Once you completely understand this, you will be able to better solve any issues faced.

Comment: I do not want first view (the top one to scroll)

Comment: I understand you. The 1st view will not scroll. It will look same the as pan gesture animation you shared. It will look like the table view started moving to top & then table view will start scrolling in same continuous touch.
Just give that Twitter Profile example a try.